# Having a 3x3 2d array and accessing array[1][3] equates to array[2][0]?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

So basically, I've encountered this code in our class:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int arr[3][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };

    printf("%d", arr[0][2]);
    printf("\n%d", arr[1][0]);

    printf("\n%d", arr[0][2 + 1]);
}
```

I'm a bit confused because the last `printf` statement is `arr[0][2 + 1]` which equates to `arr[0][3]`, but since our array dimension is 3x3 so that makes our max index value at only 2, making `arr[0][3]` out of bounds. But when I ran this thing, it displayed 4, which is the same from the second `printf` statement, which is `arr[1][0]`, why is this happening?

I was expecting something like an error that it would tell me that it is out of bounds but it proceeded to print the next index value of the array.

Comment: Expecting C to give you an "out of bounds" error is optimistic — it won't hold your hand for you; it assumes you know what you're doing, and allows you to shoot yourself in the foot if you want to.

Comment: The last `printf` is there just to confound you. Accessing the element with index = 3 is getting one more than the number of elements in a row.  You got one plus past the end.  You were lucky, as the next row starts immediately after the previous (this happens with all arrays, elements are in memory one after the other)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C doesn't perform any kind of bounds checking on arrays.  That's part of what makes it fast.  However, that also means that if you do something you're not supposed to, then your code ends up triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In this case, `arr[0][2 + 1]` goes out of bounds on the second array element, and accessing an array out of bounds is undefined behavior.  In the case of a 2D (and larger) array, each of the subarrays follows each other.  So you ended up reading what happened to be in the next memory location which happens to be `arr[1][0]`.

There's no guarantee that what you saw will always happen however.  Compilers, in the process of optimizing, will assume that no undefined behavior exists and make optimization decisions based on that assumption.

This case is explicitly mention as an example of undefined behavior in section J.2 of the C standard:

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
> given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration `int a[4][5]`) (6.5.6).

Comment: ...arrays, however, have pretty strict alignment and aliasing requirements, so as long as you don’t try to access an element outside of your array, it is safe to assume you can do stupid stuff like wraparound indexing.

Comment: @Dúthomhas No it is not safe. If I make a write access to `arr[0][3]` and then a read access to `arr[1][0]`, the compiler is free to assume that `arr[1][0]` still holds the initial value and may optimize the code accordingly. Don't write code relying on undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I've learned so much from this! So it was more on the programming language side of things, it was confusing but since you mentioned that the multidimensional arrays worked as if the indexes are laid out sequentially, I got it now, thanks again!

Comment: @Lundin, no, the compiler knows that after `arr[0][3]` comes `arr[1][0]`.  Optimization gives freedom to the compiler to do some things... but pre-ansi features are still in use to protect legacy code.  And that assumption (that the array elements are together aligned one after another) is a legacy from K&R.

Comment: @LuisColorado The compiler does not actually know that, because C does very strictly speaking actually not have multi-dimensional arrays - it has arrays of arrays. And the rules of pointer arithmetic which determine whether this is UB or not are working on array basis. One may argue that a quality implementation would never do anything but plain addition of addresses when an array is de-referenced, but compilers these days are not that simple, nor are they overly concerned about being quality implementations.

Comment: @LuisColorado -- it is undefined behavior per the Standard, and Annex J.2 even shows an example of this type of access as undefined behavior. From the upcoming C23 Standard, Annex J.2 (46): _"An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration `int a[4][5]`) (6.5.6)."_

Comment: @Lundin, the rules of arrays of arrays, and the aligment requirements that require the elements to stay together do enforce it.  It's not a question of a comittee's decision, but just a mathematical fact.

Comment: @LuisColorado Like I just explained, the "contiguousness" of arrays will mean that it will work _as long as the implementation never do anything of plain addition of addresses_ to calculate the address to access. But compilers aren't that basic, for example the 64 bit ones like to show small arrays under 8 bytes into a single register. "Ah, a `char [8]` array, I'll put that in register A". Now what's the compiler supposed to if placing a `char [2][8]` in registers A and B respectively, and then someone decides to access item `[0][8]`?

Comment: And what will happen when you try to compile legacy code written without prototypes and full of those assumptions?  IMHO, if you run legacy code, your compiler should allow you to compile legacy code and then, don't make such things.  C98 is also C and K&R C is also C.  I agree that C is a living horse that evolves to make programming more efficient, but this doesn't mean we need to rewrite all legacy code because the standards makers are so clever.   Let's discuss on a common sense feeling and don't accept things just because somebody has said it.

Comment: The argument you hold has been already addressed and resolved when the ABIs started to pass variable or undefined argument lists to the called rutine (what is called `<stdarg.h>`) and the solution found to address that is to continue using the old fashioned `PUSH` and `POP` of arguments to the stack because somebody could ask for the address of a `register` variable and well, that cannot be done.  K&R established the ordering of element in arrays at multiple levels and it is common to initialize an array carrying a side pointer that addresses cell elements by just incrementing the pointer.

Comment: @LuisColorado -- the Standard has explicitly pointed to this as an example of undefined behavior since C99. That was 25 years ago. The question is not whether you can compile legacy code without changes, but whether you can safely compile code on a contemporary compiler. This has less to do with clever standards committees and more to do with clever compiler writers who take advantage of the absence of undefined behavior in valid C programs. Perhaps those two groups intersect.

Comment: @adabsurdum, there's still running code that has neither been ANSIfied, due to diverse reasons, so compilers still recognise K&R code (e.g. no prototypes, no parameter type definition in the parameter list) and compile it correctly.  Recognise that prototypes are in use for a bit more than 25 years, and are still recognised.  So, who is right?  what about `main(argc, argv)char **argv;{printf("Welcome to K&R world\n");}` ?